# Angular 5 source files are semi-compiled with Webpack 4

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular5, webpack-4

I have an Angular 5 project that works with Webpack 3.
When I upgrade it to Webpack 4 (and doing the required changes), the typescript source files are presented after being compiled to Javascript (but not minified).

For example, I've used Angular CLI 1.7.4 to create a new project, and I ejected the Webpack config:

> yarn global add @angular/cli@1.7.4
>
> ng set --global packageManager=yarn
>
> ng new project1
>
> ng eject

Then I've updated Webpack and all of the required packages

> yarn add --dev @ngtools/webpack angular-named-lazy-chunks-webpack-plugin html-webpack-plugin url-loader webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server

And finally, I did the required changes in webpack.config.js:

- Add "mode": "development"
- Remove NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin and NamedModulesPlugin
- Replace NamedLazyChunksWebpackPlugin with AngularNamedLazyChunksWebpackPlugin
- Delete CommonsChunkPlugin and add optimization->splitChunks

When I'm running the project (with "yarn start", which calls "webpack-dev-server"), I'm seeing the typescript source files, but they're compiled to Javascript.

app.component.ts - with Webpack 3 (webpack:///./src/app/app.component.ts):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}



// WEBPACK FOOTER //
// ./src/app/app.component.ts
```

app.component.ts - with Webpack 4 (webpack:///./src/app/app.component.ts?):

```
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "AppComponent", function() { return AppComponent; });
/* harmony import */ var _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! @angular/core */ "./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js");
var __decorate = (undefined && undefined.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};

var AppComponent = /** @class */ (function () {
    function AppComponent() {
        this.title = 'app';
    }
    AppComponent = __decorate([
        Object(_angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["Component"])({
            selector: 'app-root',
            template: __webpack_require__(/*! ./app.component.html */ "./src/app/app.component.html"),
            styles: [__webpack_require__(/*! ./app.component.css */ "./src/app/app.component.css")]
        })
    ], AppComponent);
    return AppComponent;
}());
```

Here's the webpack.config.js file (most of it comes from the ng eject):

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin');
const CircularDependencyPlugin = require('circular-dependency-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const rxPaths = require('rxjs/_esm5/path-mapping');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const postcssUrl = require('postcss-url');
const postcssImports = require('postcss-import');

const { SourceMapDevToolPlugin } = require('webpack');
const { BaseHrefWebpackPlugin, PostcssCliResources } = require('@angular/cli/plugins/webpack');
const AngularNamedLazyChunksWebpackPlugin = require('angular-named-lazy-chunks-webpack-plugin');
const { AngularCompilerPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');

const entryPoints = ["inline","polyfills","sw-register","styles","vendor","main"];
const hashFormat = {"chunk":"","extract":"","file":".[hash:20]","script":""};
const baseHref = "";
const deployUrl = "";
const projectRoot = process.cwd();
const maximumInlineSize = 10;
const postcssPlugins = function (loader) {
        return [
            postcssImports({
                resolve: (url, context) => {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        let hadTilde = false;
                        if (url && url.startsWith('~')) {
                            url = url.substr(1);
                            hadTilde = true;
                        }
                        loader.resolve(context, (hadTilde ? '' : './') + url, (err, result) => {
                            if (err) {
                                if (hadTilde) {
                                    reject(err);
                                    return;
                                }
                                loader.resolve(context, url, (err, result) => {
                                    if (err) {
                                        reject(err);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        resolve(result);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                resolve(result);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                },
                load: (filename) => {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        loader.fs.readFile(filename, (err, data) => {
                            if (err) {
                                reject(err);
                                return;
                            }
                            const content = data.toString();
                            resolve(content);
                        });
                    });
                }
            }),
            postcssUrl({
                filter: ({ url }) => url.startsWith('~'),
                url: ({ url }) => {
                    const fullPath = path.join(projectRoot, 'node_modules', url.substr(1));
                    return path.relative(loader.context, fullPath).replace(/\\/g, '/');
                }
            }),
            postcssUrl([
                {
                    // Only convert root relative URLs, which CSS-Loader won't process into require().
                    filter: ({ url }) => url.startsWith('/') && !url.startsWith('//'),
                    url: ({ url }) => {
                        if (deployUrl.match(/:\/\//) || deployUrl.startsWith('/')) {
                            // If deployUrl is absolute or root relative, ignore baseHref & use deployUrl as is.
                            return `${deployUrl.replace(/\/$/, '')}${url}`;
                        }
                        else if (baseHref.match(/:\/\//)) {
                            // If baseHref contains a scheme, include it as is.
                            return baseHref.replace(/\/$/, '') +
                                `/${deployUrl}/${url}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
                        }
                        else {
                            // Join together base-href, deploy-url and the original URL.
                            // Also dedupe multiple slashes into single ones.
                            return `/${baseHref}/${deployUrl}/${url}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    // TODO: inline .cur if not supporting IE (use browserslist to check)
                    filter: (asset) => {
                        return maximumInlineSize > 0 && !asset.hash && !asset.absolutePath.endsWith('.cur');
                    },
                    url: 'inline',
                    // NOTE: maxSize is in KB
                    maxSize: maximumInlineSize,
                    fallback: 'rebase',
                },
                { url: 'rebase' },
            ]),
            PostcssCliResources({
                deployUrl: loader.loaders[loader.loaderIndex].options.ident == 'extracted' ? '' : deployUrl,
                loader,
                filename: `[name]${hashFormat.file}.[ext]`,
            }),
            autoprefixer({ grid: true }),
        ];
    };




module.exports = {
  "mode": "development",
  "resolve": {
    "extensions": [
      ".ts",
      ".js"
    ],
    "symlinks": true,
    "modules": [
      "./src",
      "./node_modules"
    ],
    "alias": rxPaths(),
    "mainFields": [
      "browser",
      "module",
      "main"
    ]
  },
  "resolveLoader": {
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules",
      "./node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules"
    ],
    "alias": rxPaths()
  },
  "entry": {
    "main": [
      "./src\\main.ts"
    ],
    "polyfills": [
      "./src\\polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "styles": [
      "./src\\styles.css"
    ]
  },
  "output": {
    "path": path.join(process.cwd(), "dist"),
    "filename": "[name].bundle.js",
    "chunkFilename": "[id].chunk.js",
    "crossOriginLoading": false
  },
  "module": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "test": /\.html$/,
        "loader": "raw-loader"
      },
      {
        "test": /\.(eot|svg|cur)$/,
        "loader": "file-loader",
        "options": {
          "name": "[name].[hash:20].[ext]",
          "limit": 1
          // "limit": 10000
        }
      },
      {
        "test": /\.(jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)$/,
        "loader": "url-loader",
        "options": {
          "name": "[name].[hash:20].[ext]",
          "limit": 10000
        }
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "use": [
          {
            "loader": "raw-loader"
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "embedded",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "use": [
          {
            "loader": "raw-loader"
          },
          {
            "loader": "webpack-angular-source-map"
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "embedded",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "sass-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": true,
              "precision": 8,
              "includePaths": []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "use": [
          {
            "loader": "raw-loader"
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "embedded",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "less-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "use": [
          {
            "loader": "raw-loader"
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "embedded",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "stylus-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": true,
              "paths": []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "use": [
          "style-loader",
          {
            "loader": "raw-loader"
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "embedded",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "use": [
          "style-loader",
          {
            "loader": "raw-loader"
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "embedded",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "sass-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": true,
              "precision": 8,
              "includePaths": []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "use": [
          "style-loader",
          {
            "loader": "raw-loader"
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "embedded",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "less-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "use": [
          "style-loader",
          {
            "loader": "raw-loader"
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "embedded",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "stylus-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": true,
              "paths": []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "test": /\.ts$/,
        "loader": "@ngtools/webpack"
      }
    ]
  },
  "plugins": [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        "context": "src",
        "to": "",
        "from": {
          "glob": "assets\\**\\*",
          "dot": true
        }
      },
      {
        "context": "src",
        "to": "",
        "from": {
          "glob": "favicon.ico",
          "dot": true
        }
      }
    ], {
      "ignore": [
        ".gitkeep",
        "**/.DS_Store",
        "**/Thumbs.db"
      ],
      "debug": "warning"
    }),
    new ProgressPlugin(),
    new CircularDependencyPlugin({
      "exclude": /(\\|\/)node_modules(\\|\/)/,
      "failOnError": false,
      "onDetected": false,
      "cwd": projectRoot
    }),
    new AngularNamedLazyChunksWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      "template": "./src\\index.html",
      "filename": "./index.html",
      "hash": false,
      "inject": true,
      "compile": true,
      "favicon": false,
      "minify": false,
      "cache": true,
      "showErrors": true,
      "chunks": "all",
      "excludeChunks": [],
      "title": "Webpack App",
      "xhtml": true,
      "chunksSortMode": function sort(left, right) {
        let leftIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(left.names[0]);
        let rightIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(right.names[0]);
        if (leftIndex > rightIndex) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (leftIndex < rightIndex) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    }),
    new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({}),
    new SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      "filename": "[file].map[query]",
      "moduleFilenameTemplate": "[resource-path]",
      "fallbackModuleFilenameTemplate": "[resource-path]?[hash]",
      "sourceRoot": "webpack:///"
    }),
    new AngularCompilerPlugin({
      "mainPath": "main.ts",
      "platform": 0,
      "hostReplacementPaths": {
        "environments\\environment.ts": "environments\\environment.ts"
      },
      "sourceMap": true,
      "tsConfigPath": "src\\tsconfig.app.json",
      "skipCodeGeneration": true,
      "compilerOptions": {}
    })
  ],
  "optimization": {
    namedModules: true,
    splitChunks: {
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: 2
    },
    noEmitOnErrors: true
  },
  "node": {
    "fs": "empty",
    "global": true,
    "crypto": "empty",
    "tls": "empty",
    "net": "empty",
    "process": true,
    "module": false,
    "clearImmediate": false,
    "setImmediate": false
  },
  "devServer": {
    "historyApiFallback": true
  }
};
```

I tried all sort of things to make it work (include using "devtool: 'source-map'"), but nothing helped.

I'd appreciate any idea on how to fix it.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out - in webpack.config.js, the "devtool" option must be set to false (as I'm using custom SourceMapDevToolPlugin):

```
module.exports = {
    "mode": "development",
    "devtool": false,
...
```

Webpack 3 worked without that definition.